# как в запрос mongodb вставить переменную

Tags: golang, mongodb

Нужно, что бы получлось после вставки так

```html
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4886db19aba9bb52b2e666"),
    "rows" : {
        "title":"муцппцп",
        "description":"5465465"
        }
    },
    "dateInsert" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:03:39.171Z")
}
```

но получается так

```html
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4886db19aba9bb52b2e666"),
    "rows" : {
        "$each" : "{"title":"муцппцп","description":"5465465"}"// тут все данные как строка идут
    },
    "dateInsert" : ISODate("2020-02-16T00:03:39.171Z")
}
```

пишу на go вот сам код

```html
type DataTechnicalService struct {
 Id                            string      `json:"_id"`
 Rows                          interface{} `json:"rows"`
}

type AutoGeneratedd struct {
 Title       string `json:"title"`
 Description string `json:"description"`
}

func (mc *MyClient) insertTechnicalServiceData(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
 setupResponse(w, r)
 var err error
 var data DataTechnicalService
 err = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&data)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
  return
 }

 str, _ := data.Rows.(string)
 str = str[:len(str)-1]
 str = strings.Replace(str, "[", "", -1)

 podcastsCollection := mc.db.Collection("technicalService")
 ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
 defer cancel()

 _, err = podcastsCollection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.M{
  "rows":                          bson.M{"$each": str},
  "dateInsert":                    time.Now(),
 })
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }
}
```

переменной **str** нужные данные но при простой вставке лежит ошибка не соблюдаю синтаксис

Answer (score 0):

Нужно

```html
var i []AutoGeneratedd
 var bM []bson.M

 if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &i); err != nil {
  fmt.Println("ugh: ", err)
 }

 for _, u := range i[:len(i)] {
  bM = append(bM, bson.M{"title": u.Title})
 }
 fmt.Println(bM)
```

и

```html
 _, err = podcastsCollection.InsertOne(ctx, bson.M{
  "rows":                          bM,

 })
```